# Adding char to List<Char> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, logic

I am trying to create `List<Char>` from `String` in Kotlin but it seems there is no inbuilt function is provided by lib. Also casting will generate error. So here is what I am doing. Please let me know if I am missing something in question. (Or we can say converting string to `List<Char>` in Kotlin).

```kotlin
var stringVal = "ABC"
var genList:List<Char> = arrayListof()
var count = 0

while (stringVal.length == genList.size) {
    // way to add stringVal to genList
   
    count++
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```kotlin
val chars = "ABC".toList()
```

`CharSequence` has a `to(Mutable)List` extension function defined in [`kotlin.text`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-list.html).

> `fun CharSequence.toList(): List<Char>`
> Returns a `List` containing all characters.
> <sub>[kotlin-stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/) / [kotlin.text](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/) / [toList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-list.html)</sub>

> `fun CharSequence.toMutableList(): MutableList<Char>`
> Returns a `MutableList` filled with all characters of this char sequence.
> <sub>[kotlin-stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/) / [kotlin.text](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/) / [toMutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-mutable-list.html)</sub>

Kotlin's standard libraries have hundreds of utility functions like this, so chances are that most of the time what you want already exists.

Many standard types that conceptually model some sort of iterable data, but are not `Iterable`, have extensions defined on them that are equivalent to those in `kotlin.collections`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by @Moira is definitely the way to go here, I would accept it.

However, the question was about adding an element to a `List<Char>`, which isn't possible in Kotlin because a `List` is immutable and yours gets initialized as an empty one, so it will stay empty.

Use a `MutableList<Char>` and simply `add` single `Char`s to it if you need it:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var genList = mutableListOf<Char>()
    genList.add('a')
    genList.add('A')
    genList.add('B')
    genList.add('C')
    println(genList)
}
```

Output:

```
[a, A, B, C]
```

Comment: Great point! Minor nitpick/addition: the value assigned to `genList` is an `ArrayList` and is therefore mutable; however, as it is assigned to a variable of type `List` any mutating operations will be unavailable. Incidentally, had OP simply omitted the type specifier, this would've worked :P

Comment: @Moira Also a good point! Thanks... I may add that to the answer later.